# How to set my own page layout as default?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, page-layout

I have create a page layout in SharePoint Designer. When ever I create a new page in my site, it applies "Body Only" page layout on that page and then I have to change it by manually selecting my own page layout from the ribbon.

How do I make my own page layout as default so every time a new page is created, my own page layout is applied to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Pagelayout and site templates**. Under section **Default setting for new pages** choose radiobutton saying **Select default pagelayout**. A selectlist will appear, select your custom pagelayout and click OK.

All your new pages should now be created using this pagelayout.